# Read uchar value from hooked method using Frida

Tags: javascript, c++, reverse-engineering, frida

How can i read value of uchar* ?

I tried many ways, it's code which i used:

```
Interceptor.attach(Module.getExportByName('libsigning.so', 'EVP_DigestSignFinal'), {
    onEnter: function (args) {
        console.log("RSA.doFinal() [VALID]")
        console.log("arg0: OpenSSL object")
        console.log("arg1: " + Memory.readUtf8String(args[1]))
        console.log("arg2: " + args[2].readUInt())
    },
    onLeave: function (retval) {
        // simply replace the value to be returned with 0
        return retval
    }
});
```

What i got:

```
RSA.doFinal() [VALID]
arg0: RSA object
arg1: 
arg2: 512
```

How it looks in ghidra:
[image]

In output I'm getting unknown character instead of real value

What is a proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you hook is [documented](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/EVP_DigestSignFinal.html)

```
int EVP_DigestSignFinal(EVP_MD_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *sig, size_t *siglen);
```

According to it's documentation the second argument receives the created signature:

> signs the data in ctx and places the signature in sig. If sig is NULL
> then the maximum size of the output buffer is written to the siglen
> parameter. If sig is not NULL then before the call the siglen
> parameter should contain the length of the sig buffer. If the call is
> successful the signature is written to sig and the amount of data
> written to siglen.

(Cryptographic) signatures are binary data and in C the type `unsigned char` is often used to store such binary data. Therefore even if it contains the name `char` you won't find any printable characters or a complete string in it.

Therefore if you want to print it as a string it will fail as the "real value" is binary data.

To read binary data you can use Frida `readByteArray` from [NativePointer](https://frida.re/docs/javascript-api/#nativepointer)